# C++ non-copyable classes and multiple inheritance, pure abstract classes

Tags: c++, interface, multiple-inheritance

We can probably agree that default copy construction is bad most of the time in C++, so it's better to disable it explicitly with either C++11 `=delete` or non-copyable classes like `boost::noncopyable`.

The question is, what happens in advanced scenarios when we use multiple inheritance or public abstract classes?

```
//Class uncopyable
class uncopyable {...};

//Interface1
class IInterface1 : private uncopyable
{
public:
 IInterface1(...)
 virtual ~IInterface1(...) = 0;
};

//Interface2
class IInterface2 : private uncopyable
{
public:
 IInterface2(...)
 virtual ~IInterface2(...) = 0;
};

//Fancy implementation
//FImpl
class FImpl : public IInterface1, public IInterface2, private : uncopyable
{
public:
 FImpl(...) {...}
 ~FImpl(...) {...};
};
```

- Is it a good practice to make every interface non-copyable (it seems it
  is, to avoid slicing)?
- Is it a good practice to add non-copyable to
  every derived class (explicit safeguard, but causes multiple
  inheritance and diamond problems?)

Comment: Your interfaces do not look like interfaces at all. They define constructors, and have no pure virtual methods (only some sort of destructor that looks like a syntax violation).

Comment: `~IInterface1(...) = 0` is just syntax error. And you do not want to make the destructors pure virtual.

Comment: Ok, fixed. Using pseudocode, not a real code.

Comment: Default copy construction isn't bad, most of the time.  In a few cases it is.  Starting your question that way doesn't help the discussion.

Comment: @BenVoigt: From coding guidelines like the ones Google uses, slicing, rule of three, and TR1 discussions, I understand it's a lot better to explicitly disable all copying functionality, unless required, coded, and tested appropriately.

Comment: @Coder: The Google guidelines are not general purpose, they appear to be optimized for the Google team (which I guess includes a lot more Java expertise than C++).  Rule of three says that default copy constructor is only bad if you define a custom assignment operator or destructor, which is not *most* classes.

Comment: Hard to tell, their motivation is to avoid bugs, and invisible performance penalties - http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#Copy_Constructors

Comment: Most of these problems are caused by having raw pointers as data members. If you stop using raw pointers (which, in any case, you should consider banning permanently from all your code), and use an appropriate alternative (`shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr`) then everything is much better. In other words, @Coder, guidelines like Google's apply if you have a group of programmers from a mixed up background (C, C++98, C++03, and C++11 and Java) trying to work together on a C++ project.programmers

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not a good idea to make interface non-copyable. For example, that prevents cloning.

And no, it's not a good idea to derive from non-copyable in every derived class, because it's just redundant.

However, in order to stop especially Visual C++ from spewing out silly-warnings, it can be a good idea to declare a copy constructor and copy assignment operator in every class that should be non-copyable.

Comment: What is cloning? Code like `IInterface1 *ptr = new FImpl();` `IInterface1 instA = *ptr;` is wrong as far as I know?

Comment: @Coder: it's very often a good idea to check the [FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/virtual-ctors.html)

Comment: Ok, it's good to know such approach exists, never heard of it before. However, I usually try to avoid cloning, as this usually means deep copies, critical section locks, nontrivial copy constructors (how do you copy a locked mutex, or handle to a GDI brush?), and so on. I usually use references to const whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

A pure virtual (interface) class has no need to enforce the memory management for the use of the interface. Implementations of pure virtual interfaces should determine their own memory management requirements (like copy and assign).

That said, value semantics allow implementations to avoid this situation entirely. A value class (copyable, assignable, etc.) is easier to reason about and use. All of the classes in the C++ library are value classes. A good example of a value class managing memory for itself is the venerable string class. Vector is also a good example. These classes have complex internal memory management requirements, yet, as a user of these classes, I don't have to be concerned with that aspect of the class. I can focus on how to use the class.

I like this [presentation](http://cppnow.org/session/value-semantics-and-concepts-based-polymorphism/) from [C++ Now](http://cppnow.org/) that shows how polymorphism is also an implementation detail. This includes the ability for a client to implement classes that can participate in the polymorphism without requiring an interface class (or any base class for that matter).

Comment: But string and vector are classes you can't derive other classes from.